# Is it possible to configure HAProxy to listen on IPV4, but send the request using IPV6?

Tags: proxy, haproxy, ipv6, ipv4

Trying to configure HAProxy to listen for requests on port ipv4(Port 80) but proxy the request through eth1 to a server using ipv6. The request must be show the ipv6 address for the request. We don't want to expose the ipv4 address.

Is this possible using HAProxy? If not, what should we look into?

Comment: I have the proxy running through eth0 to an IPv6 address. The "listen" directive is great, I wish I could specify a something in the backend config to push the proxy request through from eth1. I guess all I want, is request to come in on x.x.x.x port 80, and then use an ipv6 address I have configured for the request to the server address.

Comment: Also tried a listen line (on ipv4/port 80) with a server line to the localhost with ipv6 address, added a frontend that had the actual outbound server link.

Comment: So you only want the HAproxy <-> server connection to run over IPv6?

Comment: Thats correct, I am only planning on exposing a public ipv4 address for this haproxy server, so all of the ipv4 requests get pushed through ipv6 (so the end servers would see our public ipv6 addresses only) - we want to look as though we only have ipv6 addresses to the server we proxy.

Comment: There's a `source` keyword for both `backend` sections and `server` lines, which might help you ([docs](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#4.2-source)). It allows you for force the IP/port, and adapter which is used for outgoing connections.

Comment: thanks, I implemented the source directive, I am now seeing an error 503 (originating from HAPRoxy, and not the server I am proxying). I have a new question here: http://serverfault.com/questions/759293/haproxy-configuration-problems-with-source-directive

Comment: **The request must be show the ipv6 address for the request.** What does that mean?